# Ember computed sort not sorting in service

Tags: arrays, sorting, ember.js, computed-properties

Maybe I'm not doing it right but I'm trying to sort an array of `Ember.Object`'s by ID in descending order but they are coming out in ascending order still.

```
saidMessages: [],
```

Then I have the computed

```
sortedSaidMessages: Ember.computed.sort('saidMessages','id:desc'),
```

When I call a method from say a component it adds a new object into the main array

```
say: function(params) {
    if (ENV.environment === 'development' || ENV.environment === 'staging'){
      var thisMessage = Ember.Object.create(params);
      this._IDify(thisMessage,this.get('saidMessages'));
      this.get('saidMessages').pushObject(thisMessage);
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this._removeMessage(thisMessage,this.get('saidMessages'));
      },6000)
    }
},
```

In my template I display them like so

```
{{#each devlog.sortedSaidMessages as |message|}}
    {{devlog-message content=message}}
{{/each}}
```

But when I add items to the array, no matter if I add a few at the same time, or stagger them (say in a setTimeout function) they are still showing in ascending order (0,1,2,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [Ember.computed.sort](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort): the second argument is *the key to a property* describing how to sort. Here's what you want instead:

```
saidMessages: [],
saidMessagesSorting: ['id:desc'],
sortedSaidMessages: Ember.computed.sort('saidMessages','saidMessagesSorting'),
```

Comment: Ah okay I was miss reading how it was explaining to do it, thank you!